# how I can make comments on subversion.conf?

Tags: svn, config

How can I make comments on subversion.conf, I think that this file is similar to xml, but not 100% sure, somebody know anything more specific about this file and his "nature"..

References/links will be grateful.

Bye

Answer (score 1):

The first hit with google gives this page:
http://queens.db.toronto.edu/~nilesh/linux/subversion-howto/

It looks like a single hash mark/number sign at the beginning of the line starts a comment.

Comment: I guess you'd call the site a resounding success when people find it easier to post a question on SO than to google it.

Comment: Not any more.  Now THIS is the number 1 google result.